# Return only sequences which occur within double quotes?

Tags: java

I would like to write a method which returns only the characters in a string which occur within double quotes. Given `String input = "\"x\" y \"z\""`, I would like to return `"xz"`.

The below method returns just `"x"`, because the pattern matcher only finds one match.

```
  static String removeCharsNotInQuotes(String text) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        String withinQuotesRegex = "\"(.*?)\"";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(withinQuotesRegex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                builder.append(matcher.group(i));
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }

        return builder.toString().trim();
    }
```

Comment: javadoc of `groupCount()`: "Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern." - that is, not the number of groups from the string you are searching in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a while loop for the `matcher.find()` . For example:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    builder.append(matcher.group(1));
    builder.append(" ");
}
```

In addition `matcher.groupCount()` returns the number of groups **in your regex**, so using it makes only sense for more than one group, which you do not have.

The integer parameter for the call to `group()` denotes which of the groups **in your regex** you want to access, which for you is always `1`, since you only have one group.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `while` loop to keep finding new matches until you run out:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    // you don't need to use a for loop here. You just need group 1
    builder.append(matcher.group(1));
    // given your sample output, you don't seem to want a space between 
    // the stuff in each pair of quotes.
    builder.append(" "); 
}
```

You seem to be confused about what `find` does. It does not find all matches and put each match in a group. It only mutates the state of the matcher to the next match it finds.